# Toggle "data-attr" not value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want toggle data-attr ,not value

```
<div ng-attr="{{leftMenuClosed ? 'data-quantity' : 'data-order' }}" </div>
```

Result : if leftMenuClosed

```
<div data-quantity=""></div>
```

if !leftMenuClosed

```
<div data-order=""></div>
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: do you really want an empty div or just display nothing? Also, what is wrong with `<div ng-attr></div>` if it is false?

Comment: @Ronnie its not empty div , mb-scrollbar attr generate some block inside div ,ng-attr doesnt toggle data attr

Comment: is data-true and data-false a directive?

Answer (score 0):

ok I think I understand what you're doing. In order to use `ng-attr` you must specify the name of the attr. so `ng-attr-data` will create an attr called `data`:

```
<div ng-attr-data="{{leftMenuClosed ? 'true' : 'false' }}"></div>
```

will results in

```
<div ng-attr-data="{{leftMenuClosed ? 'true' : 'false' }}" data="true"></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-attr-data="{{leftMenuClosed ? 'true' : 'false' }}" data="false"></div>
```

depending on the value of `leftMenuClosed`. I think you can work with that

Comment: Thanks but its something else,,, i want 
<div  true></div> or 

<div false></div> not value of data

Comment: ok then you need to be more clear in your question. If data-true and data-false are not directives, what I gave you should be fine

Comment: i was write , " I want toggle data-attr ,NOT value " ,its mean ,that my problem with data-attr ,not data-att's value

Comment: yeah, I still don't understand

Comment: please ,check my question one more time